# Calling WCF after bypassing web proxy

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, proxy

I want to call wcf service hosted outside my netwerk. When i call that wcf from my code i got proxy authentication error as i am calling from machine which is covered with firewall.

So how i can provide my firewall proxy id/password programmatically to call the wcf service.

Somehow i have mananged to download proxy classes from that outside server which can call the wcf service but when i call any function i get the same error.

I have tried calling that code but i got error.

Comment: What error did you get

Comment: The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672477/consuming-a-web-service-through-an-internet-proxy-server-using-a-wcf-client-in